# Object persistence in class between projects

Tags: c#, class

I know I shouldn't have to ask this but whatever it is I am missing is driving me nuts!  I have done this many times before and I can only put it down to old age and slight senility.

I have a class with two objects that get initialized in the constructor...

```
public class EbayFunctions
{
    private static ApiContext apiContext = null;
    private static List<StoreCategoriesFlattened> storeCategories =  new List<StoreCategoriesFlattened>();

    public EbayFunctions()
    {
        ApiContext apiContext = GetApiContext();
        List<StoreCategoriesFlattened> storeCategories = GetFlattenedStoreCategories();
    }
    public string GetStoreCategoryIdForItem(string category)
    {
       var result = storeCategories.Find(x => x.CCDatabaseMatch == category);
       return ""; //Ignore will return a value
    }
}
```

then I have a forms app (test harness) that makes use of the class and on button click I call a method...

```
namespace EbayTestHarness
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void cmdGetEbayStoreCatID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EbayFunctions ebf = new EbayFunctions();
            string ddd = ebf.GetStoreCategoryIdForItem("Motors > Bikes");

        }
    }
}
```

However `apiContext` persists between calls but `storeCategories` gets populated on `EbayFunctions ebf = new EbayFunctions();` and is null when `string ddd = ebf.GetStoreCategoryIdForItem("Motors > Bikes");` is called.

I know its something stupid but what am I missing?

Comment: I dont understand the meaning of `persistence` in the question title.

Comment: @leppie The OP is expecting the values of `apiContext` and `storeCategories` to "persist" between instances since they're `static`.

Comment: @DStanley: Thanks, should have thought of that! I blame Monday.

Comment: @leppie think yourself lucky I have to blame old age!! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
private static ApiContext apiContext = null;
private static List<StoreCategoriesFlattened> storeCategories =  new List<StoreCategoriesFlattened>();

public EbayFunctions()
{
    ApiContext apiContext = GetApiContext();  // local!!
    List<StoreCategoriesFlattened> storeCategories = GetFlattenedStoreCategories();  // local!!
}
```

You're not setting the static fields - you're introducing *local variables* that then go out of scope and are (eventually) garbage collected.  Take out the type indicators to set the static fields:

```
public EbayFunctions()
{
    apiContext = GetApiContext();
    storeCategories = GetFlattenedStoreCategories();
}
```

Also, as [@PatrickHofman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman) points out, the initialization of static members should be done once - preferably in a static constructor:

```
static EbayFunctions()
{
    apiContext = GetApiContext();
    storeCategories = GetFlattenedStoreCategories();
}
```

Comment: Yet another total glaring error i make! I really am started to think im losing it.  Maybe a career change to shelf stacking is overdue!  Thanks!

Comment: `this` cannot be applied to `static` fields. Use the class name instead.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Good catch - I removed that part and added your suggestion of using a static constructor.